# How to retrieve data json api to form in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, http-post

I have a form textfield and dropdown and I have data productCode = "INQPREPAID50" i want to become 50000 in dropdown field "Nominal".

This my response json:

```
{
  "responseCode": "0000",
  "responseMessage": "Success",
  "date": "20200320",
  "time": "142352",
  "currency": "IDR",
  "content": {
    "productCode": "INQPREPAID50",
    "productName": "INQ Prabayar 50.000"
  },
}
```

How to retrieve productCode = "INQPREPAID50" become to only number 50000 in dropdown "Nominal" and display data json api in next page screen. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some function to parsing like

```
setNumber(String title) {
    if (title.contains('50') {
      return 50000;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
```

so just call in your text/widget example

```
Text("${setNumber(productCode)}",
```

Comment: how defined and call productCode in dropdown. thanks

Comment: and how to retrieve data from the api and show in the flutter drop down options.